# Getting PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class Services_Twilio_TinyHttp could not be converted to string

Tags: php, twilio

I am setting up Twilio and trying to send a simpe sms to my personal phone. but all i get is this error in title + this happens on Services/Twilio/Resource.php on line 127:

```
public function __toString() {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
        if ($key !== "client" && $key !== "subresources") {
            $out[$key] = (string)$value; <----------------HERE
        }
    }
    return json_encode($out);
}
```

My code on controller look like this:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
        try {
            foreach($listUsers as $user){
                $sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
                    $phone, // From this number
                    $user['phone'], // To this number
                    $message
                );
            }
            $data['results'] = "success";
            $data['message'] = "Your message have been sent successfully";
            echo json_encode($data);
        } catch (Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
            $data['results'] = "error";
            $data['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

I am sitting for hours now, can't seem to figure out the problem. Maybe some one have used this Twilio and could give me a hint atleast where to look..

Whole error:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Services_Twilio_TinyHttp could not be converted to string in ../Services/Twilio/Resource.php on line 127, referer:
```

Comment: & the exact error message is?

Comment: One of the ironies of PHP is that you can't actually `catch` a Catchable fatal error.

Comment: "Errors" are not *exceptions* and cannot be caught by `catch`, only by an error handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors are not Exceptions, they are not `throw`n and cannot be `catch`ed. Errors can be handled by error handlers registered with [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/set_error_handler). Now, there are several fatal error types like `E_ERROR` or `E_CORE_ERROR`, which cannot be handled by any error handler; these errors are fatal and stop script execution, period (or *full stop* if you prefer ;)). But there's also an `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR`, which is described as such:

> Catchable fatal error. It indicates that a probably dangerous error occurred, but did not leave the Engine in an unstable state. If the error is not caught by a user defined handle (see also `set_error_handler()`), the application aborts as it was an `E_ERROR`.
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

So you could handle these errors with a custom error handler. You should mostly do that to possibly write custom error logs or send alert mails, but you should nonetheless terminate the script afterwards (though you are not forced to). It's just being described as a *"catchable error"*, though it has nothing to do with `try..catch`.

---

The cause of the error in your case is that you're trying to cast an object to a string, but the object doesn't like that. You should look at the documentation for the class how the object wants to be treated and how you can get the data you want out of it. `(string)` does not work, plain and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert any of the resources, eg $client->account, $message = $client->account->messages->get('MM123') to a string, by calling echo on it or similar.

It looks like somewhere you are trying to cast the http client ($client->http) to a string. The http client doesn't define a tostring method.